# Why does this type of substitution work in integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, substitution

Source:[Integrate Form $du / (a^2 + u^2)^{3/2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17666/integrate-form-du-a2-u23-2)

> How does one integrate $du / (a^2 + u^2)^{3/2}$?
>
> We want to express $(a^2 + u^2)^{3/2}$ as something without square
>   roots. We want to use some form of the Pythagorean trigonometric
>   identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$. Multiplying each side by
>   $\frac{a^2}{\cos^2 x}$, we get $a^2 \tan^2 x + a^2 = a^2 \sec^2 x$,
>   which is in the desired form. of (sum of two squares) = (something
>   squared).
>
> This suggests that we should use the substitution $u^2 = a^2 \tan^2
>  x$. Equivalently, we substitute $u = a \tan x$ and $du = a \sec^2 x
>  dx$. Then $$ \int \frac{du}{(a^2 + u^2)^{3/2}} 
>  = \int \frac{a \sec^2 x \, dx}{(a^2 + a^2 \tan^2 x)^{3/2}}. $$ Applying the trigonometric identity considered above, this becomes $$
>  \int \frac{a \sec^2 x \, dx}{(a^2 \sec^2 x)^{3/2}}
>  = \int \frac{dx}{a^2 \sec x} = \frac{1}{a^2} \int \cos x \, dx, $$ which can be easily integrated as $$
>  =\frac{1}{a^2} \sin x. $$ Since we set $u = a \tan x$, we substitute back $x = \tan^{-1} (\frac ua)$ to get that the answer is $$
> =\frac{1}{a^2} \sin \tan^{-1} \frac{u}{a}. $$ Since $\sin \tan^{-1} z = \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2 + 1}}$, this yields the desired result of  $$
> =\frac{u/a}{a^2 \sqrt{(u/a)^2 + 1}}
>  = \frac{u}{a^2 (a^2 + u^2)^{1/2}}. $$

I have a doubt regarding the above method of substitution.I agree that "we set $u = a \tan x$" but why should "we substitute back $x = \tan^{-1} (\frac ua)$"?

I mean $x$ could even be $n\pi+\tan^{-1} (\frac ua)$? This is my doubt.

Another doubt.$\sin \tan^{-1} \frac{u}{a}=\sin (\sin^{-1} \pm (\frac{u/a} {\sqrt{(u/a)^2 + 1}}))$.So how do we decide to take the + sign or the - sign?

Why does these type of substitution work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does not matter. If you consider $x=n\pi+\tan^{-1} (\frac ua)$, then the $n\pi$ part will go to the integration constant part and make a new integration constant. That's it. As far as an indefinite integral is concerned, the above substitution is well justified.

Comment: I like your explaination to the question.But I  have another doubt regarding the approach.$\sin \tan^{-1} \frac{u}{a}=\sin (\sin^{-1} \pm (\frac{u/a} {\sqrt{(u/a)^2 + 1}}))$.So how do we decide to take the + sign or the - sign?

Comment: @MathJack Depends on the domain of $u$. It will be different for different $u$. I think the $\pm$ should be added. Or as most solutions assume by convention, neglect the negative solution and take the positive one.

Comment: So you mean in case of definite integration suppose $u$ is from -2 to -1 then taking the positive sign will give wrong answer?Right?

Comment: @MathJack Well, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why does this work- for integrals with $a^2 + u^2$ factors especially in the denominator or under radicals, trigonometric substitution frequently makes the integral feasible.

Quality calculus texts typically have a table showing which substitution to make and which form of  $sin^2 x + cos^2 x =1$ will be most helpful.

The bottom line is $a^2 \pm u^2$ frequently lends itself to trigonometric substitution.